# TFS: how to limit field integer value

Tags: tfs

There are two integer fields ('lowest' and 'highest') in TFS work item. Is there any possibility to limit the value of the 'lowest'  to be not greater that value of the 'highest'?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do this sort of comparison in TFS Work Items.

[This MSDN page lists the available work item rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339703.aspx).

- REQUIRED
- READONLY
- EMPTY
- FROZEN
- CANNOTLOSEVALUE
- NOTSAMEAS
- VALIDUSER
- ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE
- MATCH
- ALLOWEDVALUES
- SUGGESTEDVALUES
- PROHIBITEDVALUES
- DEFAULT
- COPY
- SERVERDEFAULT

Comment: Probably there is some workaround for that? Configure "ProhibitedValues" rule to work with expressions, not with constant, for example? Or create 'custom' rule for fields?

Comment: These rules don't support greater than / less than comparison operators.

Comment: I have similar requirement. I want a field to have a double value and when the states changes, that it becomes cumulative, so I need to prohibit the value presently there and ensure the new value is greater than what is there.. Any ideas on how to do this?