# TFS 2018 - Logical operations between field values (addition / subtraction)

Tags: templates, tfs, tfs-workitem

I am working with TFS 2018 and editing work item templates to add custom fields.
I need those fields (of type integer) not allowed to enter negative values.
In addition, I wanted to ask if it is possible to perform logical operations between them, that is, complete two different fields and that the sum of them is stored in a third field as an accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

In short we cannot achieve that as no such rules in TFS.

We can only apply a field based on the existing rules. Please see [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts) and [Assign conditional-based values and rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/assign-conditional-based-values-and-rules?view=vsts#syntax-structure-for-conditional-elements) for details.

Similar thread for your reference : [TFS: how to limit field integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620189/tfs-how-to-limit-field-integer-value)

However for the requirement "`not allowed to enter negative values`". As a workaround you can try to [Define pick list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/define-pick-lists?view=vsts) and use the `ALLOWEDVALUES` element to specify a list of values that a user must specify. That means you have to add all the possible values (**do not include the negative values** ) to the list.

For example :

```
<FieldDefinition name="Integer01" refname="integer.01" type="Integer">
  <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
    <LISTITEM value="1" />
    <LISTITEM value="2" />
    <LISTITEM value="3" />
    <LISTITEM value="4" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  <HELPTEXT>integer TEST 01</HELPTEXT>
</FieldDefinition>
```

[image]